# Do the all coins/tokens have the corresponding network exploring sites/tools?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I see that Bitcoin has [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/), Ethereum has [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/). What about other coins and tokens. Is it obligatory for the given coin/token to have such blockchain exploring site/tool, is it a best practice or a voluntary measure?

Answer (score 1):

All open source cryptocurrency project should have a community which voluntarily elects to support its ecosystem. At the beginning, block explorers for said cryptocurrency project are run on a voluntary basis, but as it gains traction, there will eventually be an economic incentive to provide said service.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of them. I think Ethereum is the luckiest in this regard. Apart from the explorers you mentioned, there are free blockchain analytics tools liks c-hound.ai for further analysis and visualization of ETH / ERC20 data. If only things like this existed for all coins...